# How to use config:sensitive:set command in Magento 2 CLI?

Tags: magento2, command-line

I notice there are two commands, `config:set` to *Change system configuration* and `config:sensitive:set` to *Set sensitive configuration values*.

I learned Sensitive configuration values hold restricted or confidential information (e.g. - keys, username, password, personally identifiable info) and store settings to `app/etc/env.php`.

I use `config:set` frequently but how can I use `config:sensitive:set` practically? What is the difference between them? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`bin/magento config:set` sets **any non-sensitive configuration value by its configuration path**

**Non - Sensitive Configurations includes:**

- URLs
- IP addresses
- Ports
- Hostnames
- Domain names
- Paths (e.g., custom paths, proxy host, proxy port)
- “modes” (e.g, sandbox mode, debug mode, test mode)
- SSL (only for non-payment)
- E-mail recipients
- Administrative settings between systems (e.g., password expiration limits)

**While**

`bin/magento config:sensitive:set` sets **any sensitive configuration value by its configuration path**

**Sensitive Configurations includes:**

- Keys (such as API keys)
- Usernames and passwords
- E-mail addresses
- Any personally identifiable information (e.g., address, phone number, date of birth, government identification number, etc.)

Hope this help you to Understand Concept.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I asked how to use this `config:sensitive:set` command practically. As I mentioned, I use `config:set` frequently but want to know how to use `config:sensitive:set`. Please let me know if you have any practical examples. Thank You again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that sensitive configs not possible to grab with `bin/magento app:config:dump`
I think this can help to understand  better.

**Sensitive and environment settings**

This scope is a very huge part which includes a lot of things and there is a short list of useful links to the official Magento DevDocs documentation:

```
Set configuration values
Sensitive and system-specific
Magento Enterprise B2B Extension configuration paths reference
Other configuration paths reference
```

**Example of how to set sensitive settings**

```
shared config app/etc/config.php
sensitive or system-specific app/etc/env.php:
```

```
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\TypePool">
       <arguments>
          <!-- sensitive config items -->
          <argument name="sensitive" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="payment/paypal_express/merchant_id" xsi:type="string">1</item>
             <!-- keys, password, emails, personally identifiable information -->
          </argument>
          <!-- environment specific config items -->
          <argument name="environment" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="payment/paypal_express/debug" xsi:type="string">1</item>
             <!-- URLs, IPs, hosts, modes sandbox/live, email recipients -->
          </argument>
       </arguments>
    </type>
```

Sensitive info doesn't get exported with bin/magento app:config:dump. use env. params, e.g. CONFIG__DEFAULT__PAYMENT__TEST__PASWORD for payment/test/password

```
bin/magento app:config:dump:
```

```
system-specific > app/etc/env.php
shared > app/etc/config.php
sensitive - skipped
```

```
bin/magento config:sensitive:set:
```

```
writes to app/etc/env.php
```

[Link to the topic](https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes/blob/master/1.%20Magento%20Architecture%20and%20Customization%20Techniques/3.%20Utilize%20configuration%20XML%20and%20variables%20scope.md#sensitive-and-environment-settings)

Comment: Please add more details. If link is expired answer is invalid