# How to set an encrypted configuration value using the standard Magento CLI?

Tags: magento2, cli, command-line, magento2.4.3.p1

I'm trying to use the Magento2 `config:sensitive:set` CLI command to set a sensitive configuration value, but Magento is throwing the following error:

```
There are no sensitive configurations to fill
```

I've already searched the web, came across [one Magento stackexchange question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331898/how-to-use-bin-magento-configset-for-obscure-encrypted-values), [and another one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294135/how-to-use-configsensitiveset-command-in-magento-2-cli), as well as a [Magento2 GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28994), but none of the suggested answers worked for me.

Saving via the admin panel works fine, I'm looking to make use of the core Magento `config:sensitive:set` CLI command.

The field is defined as `obscure`, it's added to `Magento\Config\Model\Config\TypePool` as `sensitive`, and also the backend model assigned in `config.xml`:

`system.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="tax">
            <group id="my_custom_group" translate="label" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <field id="my_field" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>some label</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

`di.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\TypePool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sensitive" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tax/my_custom_group/my_field" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

`config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <tax>
            <my_custom_group>
                <my_field backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted"/>
            </my_custom_group>
        </tax>
    </default>
</config>
```

Anyone got this working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `app:config:dump` to export sensitive configs to `app/etc/env.php`, then you are able to run `config:sensitive:set` command.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research of my own, on a clean Magento 2.4.4 installation, it turns out that I mixed two separate issues in my question.

My investigation showed that:

**One thing is setting encrypted configuration values**, which depends only on the configuration of the `backend_model` in `system.xml`, and can be done by both the `config:set` as well as the `config:sensitive:set` commands. However, once the fields are locked after running `app:config:dump` or after using `config:set` with the `--lock-env` option, in order to change the value with `config:set` you **must** use the `--lock-env` option (`config:sensitve:set` will still work fine).

**Another thing is using the `config:sensitive:set` command**: as stated by @TuVan, it can be used only after the `app:config:dump` command was used.

I'm not sure what would be the exact use case of using `config:sensitive:set`, when I can always use `config:set --lock-env`, but that's out of the scope of this question :-)